# How to get the X-Frame-Options value from a website URL's Response Headers in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, iframe, client-side, x-frame-options

I need to find out if a URL can be previewed in an iFrame (some users will want this feature - and may have a url set to allow displaying in an iFrame). I want to check for an `X-Frame-Options` value of `Deny` or `SameOrigin`

I found a lot of examples of making an http client get request to api's. But I am having trouble finding an example for my specific use case.

I just need to return the headers after requesting a url. Below is one example of the many I have tried.

How is the X-Frame-Options value fetched from a URL, client-side, using Angular?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebUrlPreviewService {
  private requestHeaders: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    this.requestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.requestHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  }

  getResponseHeaders(url: string):Observable<HttpResponse<HttpHeaders>> {
    return this.http.get<HttpHeaders>(url, {observe: 'response'});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to return the headers after requesting a url.

If I understood your problem correctly, you only want to retrieve back the headers. To do that, you can use HttpClient's [HEAD request](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#head) to only get the response's headers without the body.

What is HEAD, from [Mozilla docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)

> The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that are returned if the specified resource would be requested with an HTTP GET method. Such a request can be done before deciding to download a large resource to save bandwidth, for example.

**Service**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebUrlPreviewService {
  private requestHeaders: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   headRequest(url: string):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.head(url, {observe: 'response'}); //is observe property necessary to make this http call? If not you can remove it.
  }
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private webUrlPreviewService: WebUrlPreviewService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.webUrlPreviewService.headRequest("https://api.github.com").subscribe(
      (data: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.headers.get('ETag'));
        console.log(data.headers.get('X-Frame-Options'));
      }

    )
  }
}
```

**console log results**

```
HttpResponse {headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://api.github.com/"…}

W/"5ce06fd8cae5bfa1bcfcf398e0d07415"

null
```

As you can see, `data.headers.get('X-Frame-Options')` returns null. That is because api.github.com Http Headers has set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` **not to expose** `X-Frame-Options`.

E.g. exposed custom headers does not include X-Frame-Options.
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers →ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type`

Hence, do note that your backend should set that `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to include `X-Frame-Options`.

[**simple stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mxxpt)

Comment: This answers a lot of the question, however not specific to my use case where I am trying to determine if some other entity's website can be displayed in our iframe.

Comment: @JoJo did you figure it out?